# How can you get OSX if your hard drive crashed and you don't have the original DVD anymore?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, dvd

Yesterday my HD died. I thought about buying a new disk and reinstalling, but I can't find the original DVD that came with the machine (it's a MacBook 5.1, it came with 10.5). Suppose I want to buy and install a new operating system, how can I do it, considering that boxed dvds are no longer sold?

Comment: Replacement media are always available from Apple and Box DVD Are also still for sale first party from Apple. What makes you say DVD are no longer sold?

Comment: @bmike: not of lion or mountain lion. They are only available as digital downloads.

Comment: DVD of 10.7 and higher were never made/sold by Apple, so you always need a 10.6.x DVD if you have no OS or one that can't start you on the App Store path.

Answer (score 4):

In the past AppleCare has been able to send replacement system discs.  I would assume the same holds true today but my only doubt stems from the age of the Mac, since it may be unsupported by AppleCare.  It's definitely worth a call though...

1. Call 1-800-APLCARE (Or find your Apple support number [HERE](http://support.apple.com/kb/HE57) if you're outside of the US/Canada)
2. Give them your serial number (found on your Mac, underneath your battery)
3. Explain that you have misplaced the gray system discs that came with your Mac and that you need replacement discs in order to reinstall your operating system.

Hopefully they are still able to provide replacements!

Comment: I think the telephone number that you have given, would only be applicable to US (and possibly canadian residents), but not to the rest of us.

Comment: @Simon Sorry about that, I've edited my answer to include Apple's directory of international support numbers.

Comment: Thats fine. Thanks for editing, so that we can all find the correct telephone no.

Answer (score 3):

OS X 10.6 DVDs are still available from Apple for $19.99: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. What is the official policy when osx 10.6 will be dismantled. Will they just provide an embedded ROM with the original OS ?

Comment: I don't think there's any official policy; I'm quite surprised it's still available this late. I wouldn't expect them to spend the effort to be made available in any new forms (and Macs don't have replaceable ROMs, so that's out). In fact, I half suspect that the reason it's still available at all is that they have unsold inventory and they decided it was easier to keep selling it than write it off (in which case it'll probably just vanish from the store when stock runs out).

Comment: Ok, but if in the future you lose the hard drive completely, how are you supposed to reinstall from the media, if you can't even boot the system ?

Comment: No way to tell for sure until it happens. AppleCare (@Mr Rabbit's answer) is likely to work longer, but that's not certain either.

Comment: Apple tends to support the two prior releases of operating systems.  This is seen with the Software Update Service in OS X Server, since it will only serve clients running 10.6 or newer.  It's also possible that Apple has kept 10.6 around just to keep an upgrade path available for older Macs since it's the oldest OS to include the App store, which is obviously necessary for purchasing Lion / Mountain Lion.  Just food for thought.